# my python code comes up with errors if I define the variable people and if i don't define the variable people

Tags: python

```
import random
people=0
def intake (testage):
    if testage <= 18:
        print("Person accepted!")
        people=people+1
    else:
        print("Person Denied!")
while people <= 150:
    age=random.randint(0,81)
    intake(age)
print("At capacity!")
```

on line 2 the variable people comes up with errors if I define it or if I don't define it

Comment: Note that using globals is a really bad idea - it makes code hard to read, and hard to use. Instead, return a value from your function and use that to do something. If you need to have data accessible from a range of functions, consider making a class.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning to the variable `people` from inside the function `intake`. This makes the function `intake`'s version of `people` different from the one that's defined outside the function.

To use the same `people` inside `intake`, you need to declare `people` as `global`.

```
import random
people=0
def intake (testage):
    global people # declare people as global
    if testage <= 18:
        print("Person accepted!")
        people=people+1 # now, people is the same one as above
    else:
        print("Person Denied!")
while people <= 150:
    age=random.randint(0,81)
    intake(age)
print("At capacity!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`import random;

people=0;

def intake (testage):
    global people
    if testage <= 18:
        print("Person accepted!");
        people += 1;
    else:
        print("Person Denied!");
        
while people <= 150:
    age=random.randint(0,81);
    intake(age);
print("At capacity!")`